# How to Pass Email Addresses into Recipient Emails Array - AWS SES

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I am having issues with passing an array of email addresses into AWS SES email recipients. I have a MySql query that generates an array `$emails_array_from_query` of email addresses:

```
for ($i=0; $i <$numrows; $i++) {
    $stmt->fetch();
    array_push($emails_array_from_query, $emailAddress);
};
```

I need to pass this array into SES client. AWS requires this format:

```
$recipient_emails = ['recipient1@example.com','recipient2@example.com'];
```

I tried to `implode` and `json_encode` the array that I received from MySQL query but none of it works and I am not sure what else to do. Here is what I tried:

```
$recipient_emails_to_pass =  "'" . implode("','",$emails_array_from_query) . "'";
```

and then I pass this this way:

```
$recipient_emails = [$recipient_emails_to_pass;]
```

I also tried this approach:

```
$recipient_emails_to_pass =  json_encode($emails_array_from_query);

$recipient_emails = [$recipient_emails_to_pass;]
```

None of these work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!